# Exchange 2007 - email body disappeared

Tags: exchange-server-2007

Got an issue with email being sent after the upgrading of email server from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2007. The problem is the html emails (with arbitrary attachment) sent by java application (using apache components) have no body instead the body is being added as attachment (ATT00001.htm). Have you encountered this problem? This happens after the upgrade, before these emails were alright. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution to this issue. The problem was in the component that we're using to send email. We just upgraded apache common mail from 1.1 to 1.2, it fixes the whole problem. There's bug when sending email with attachments using the previous component. You might be considering to upgrade also when you're using this component. Other email clients seemed to read email and render it correctly but others have problems with it.

Cheers!